# Solidity store and count times color been voted for

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

So I am just learning solidity and I want to count how many times a color has been chosen. Now I know I could do:

```
uint public red = 0;

function voteRed() public 
 { 
 red++;
 }
```

But I would have to code in each color before hand.

What I want to do is let the user 'vote' for their color using a string.

If the color has been chosen it simply adds +1 to the color.

If the color has not been chosen, its adds the color name and then adds +1.

So lets say I want to vote 'Yellow'. I send the string 'Yellow' to the contract and it stores the data 'Yellow' plus the amount of times its been voted for (1).

If another person votes 'Yellow' it simply adds +1 to the 'Yellow' data (2)

And so on...

So im thinking it could be something like:

```
function voteColor(string memory color) public 
 { 
 // how to store the data and count
 }
```

But I am not sure how to store the color and the counter for that color.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a simple mapping: `mapping(string => uint256)`.
Keep in mind that any String is initialized with `0`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

contract Bla {

    mapping(string => uint256) colors;
    
    function voteColor(string memory color) public { 
        colors[color]++;
    }
    
    function getColorCount(string memory color) public view returns (uint256) {
        return colors[color];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah this is great! Can I ask a couple more things? How would I be able to return a list of all colors and their votes and also reset all colors and their votes?

Comment: You can't loop through the keys of a mapping. Easiest workaround: Track all keys (in your case colors) in an auxilary array when voted. Then, for a list of all colors and respective votes loop through the array and retrieve values from mapping. The other way around, for reseting all votes for colors, simply loop through the array, access the color via the mapping and set the voteCount of a color to zero.